# how to export data from gridview to excel 2003,2007,2010 without warning message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview

I am trying to export data from gridview to excel. I have office 2010 installed on my pc. When i am trying to open excel file it gives me error i.e. "the file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension c#".

My Code for exporting gridview:

```
Protected Sub btnexptoexcel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexptoexcel.Click
    Try
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Complaint_Details.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

            grd_ComplaintDetails.AllowPaging = False


            grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White
            For Each cell As TableCell In grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderRow.Cells
                cell.BackColor = grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderStyle.BackColor
            Next
            For Each row As GridViewRow In grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows
                row.BackColor = Color.White
                For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                    If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                        cell.BackColor = grd_ComplaintDetails.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = grd_ComplaintDetails.RowStyle.BackColor
                    End If
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode"
                Next
            Next

            grd_ComplaintDetails.RenderControl(hw)
            Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
            Response.Write(style)
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.[End]()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        div_Msg.InnerText = "Can not generate Excel File"
    End Try

End Sub
```

My question is when i open file (in MSOffice 2003, 2007 or 2010) it shouldnt give me file extension error...
Can you please tell me what are the changes i should made in the code???

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it, try saving your file as `.xlsx` instead (**excel 2007+**)

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Complaint_Details.xlsx")
```

Also, I suggest trying this free library to deal with `xlsx` Excel files. **EPPLUS** is very good. [epplus.codeplex.com](http://epplus.codeplex.com)

If you need specifically `xls` files (**excel 2003** and older), they're not supported by EPPLUS but you can use this other library **NPOI** https://npoi.codeplex.com/ that supports them

Comment: Thanks for reply... I replace my code as per your comment but it gives me error i.e. "excel cannot open the file because the file format is not valid.".. Can you please help me??

Comment: @KishorRajendraKulkarni I can't, I don't know what you're doing... I suggest rewriting your entire procedure using EPPLUS and create a **valid** `xlsx` file following the provided sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

The [Article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx) from microsoft says Excel uses the following extensions:

- **.xls** – Is The Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Binary file format (BIFF8).
- **.xlsx** –The default Office Excel 2007 XML-based file format. Cannot store Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro code or Microsoft Office Excel 4.0 macro sheets (.xlm).
- **.xlt** – The Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Binary file format (BIFF8) for an Excel template.
- **.xlsm**    The Office Excel 2007 XML-based and macro-enabled file format. Stores VBA macro code or Excel 4.0 macro sheets (.xlm).
- **.xltx**    The default Office Excel 2007 file format for an Excel template. Cannot store VBA macro code or Excel 4.0 macro sheets (.xlm).
- **.xla** The Excel 97-2003 Add-In, a supplemental program that is designed to run additional code. Supports the use of VBA projects.

Your preference is  **MSOffice 2003, 2007 or 2010**

So you have to choose

`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Complaint_Details.xlsx")` instead for 
`Complaint_Details.xls"`

Comment: Thanks for reply... I replace my code as per your comment but it gives me error i.e. "excel cannot open the file because the file format is not valid.".. Can you please help me??

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue.  I finally opened what RenderControl was outputting with Notepad and see that it is actually a web page regardless of the extension is.  That is why you get the warning message.  The user actually has to save from Excel as an Excel file.

One of the other downsides is that what is in the grid renders all of the code also.  So, the column headers will link back to a doPostBack function and hyperlinks will still have references that are invalid.

I have seen this method posted many times, but it is not really a perfect solution.